# Using TableAdapters or programatically to insert?

Tags: c#, mysql, tableadapter

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and wondering what the difference is between using `TableAdapter` to make and run queries and using `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();`.  Surely they're both the same? However, `TableAdapter` looks more secure as it can be used to stop SQL injection.

I'm wondering this because with TableAdapters you just have to create an SQL statement and then call that statement, passing in any required parameters. Doing it all programatically you'd have to instantiate an SQL command, create the query, bind the parameters, open the connection, execute the query, and then close the connection.

So why are a lot of people running SQL queries programatically rather than the easy way such as using a `TableAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just about as much work to setup a TableAdapter as it is to setup a SqlCommand. You are not describing it fully.
TableAdapters are typically used in data binding scenarios in user interfaces so that any pending CRUD operations can be done with one call to Update. This is just a less appropriate way to architect a data access layer, for example.
And... SqlCommands absolutely protect against SQL Injection assuming you actually use SqlParameters.

Comment: I agree however programatically running a query it is much more work using the SqlCommand. Is their much difference with using a TableAdapter and a SqlCommand? Efficiency? Or anything else?

Comment: @Poltergeist I doubt there is much difference in efficiency, TableAdapters are just wrapping those command, parameters and connections - it is not at all using different technology.

Comment: TableAdapters adds strong typing and frees you from most low-level stuff. It is so much nicer to work with these as with SqlCommand. That said, if you get the taste for programming on a higher level, do check out the Entity Framework.